# How to render a React component with a express router?

Tags: html, reactjs, express

So I have began my project as a React single page application. But it turns out it would be more convenient to have a basic back-end for rendering the pages and have a real routing.
Plus I have some variables that need to be accessible from all pages, and putting them as props to all the components is really heavy. So sending them with the pages could be a solution.
So I added Express, and I can now render a basic HTML page with it.
But I don't know how I am going to link my react component to this html file. Or pass it the needed variables.

I used react-router-dom but it doesn't support page refreshing. And it doesn't help with having global variables needing to be accessible from all components.

Here in my index.js you can see how I render my basic html file, and also at the end and commented, how my react component was rendered before adding express.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('./public/views/loginView.html' , { root : __dirname});
});

app.use(router);
app.listen('8080');

// const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");
// wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<App />, wrapper) : false;
```

Here my loginView.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- links and scripts -->
        <title>The login page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a simple way to link my html file with its react component and render it ?
If not, is there another way to make some variables (which are not constants) accessible from every react component (maybe react-redux) ?

Answer (score 0):

So with React you want to create a production ready bundle. This normally involves splitting the bundle up so you aren't serving a 5+Mb file to the user to download (using 4G for example with poor connection would take too long) and minifying and uglifying the code (so no one steals your code). These bundled javascript files would then be hosted on your server with reference to them in the HTML file.

The express app would then go along the lines off any route just display the HTML file e.g. `router.get('*', (req, res) => res.send('index.html))`.

I would recommend using webpack to create the bundle as it helps with the splitting and minifying etc. Take a look at webpack for development and production aswell as create-react-app for quick project setup.